# Any suggestions with Bluetooth in python please

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

IM stuck with a project i have been working on. Im trying to link my pi with bluetooth, and cant seem to get the bluetooth working. I know I have to make it a bluetooth server, but my code doesnt seem to work...`

```
import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()`
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is this bluetooth module?  pybluez?

Comment: are you getting errors? or is nothing happeneing?